# Custom specific error messages for failed tests with Chai+Mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a unit test for a function and I am having it check against a few dozen pieces of test data. If the function does not work with one of the test cases, I would like it to display the particular piece of data where the function failed.

In my case, I have about a hundred functions in the backend I am writing tests for, and for each I am writing a few Chai.js `assert()` cases that check against many pieces of test data. I don't want to have it print out the individual tests of the same function across dozens of pieces of data as I would like to keep the log readable when running the tests across the entire backend.

Here is my current way of writing the tests:

```
context('relative urls should be removed', function () {
  it('data should initially contain relative urls', async function () {
    assert(testHTML.every(containsRelativeURLs));
  });
  // (run testHTML through my function here)
  it('data should end with no relative urls', async function () {
    assert(!testHTML.every(containsRelativeURLs));
  })
});
```

Please let me know if I am misunderstanding the proper way to write unit tests. If there is a cleaner or more standard way to do this, I would love to know.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you are doing, the output you are getting, and how you would like the output to be different? Your question is really vague and it would be helpful to see some concrete examples.

Comment: what is `containsRelativeURLs`? Does it return a Promise?

Answer (score 0):

`assert` can take two parameters - the first is your assertion, the second is a message. You can use the message param to log the info.

```
describe('it passes all the tests /', ()=>{
    testData.forEach(testAsync =>
      it('should pass this test', async (done) => 
        const result = await testAsync
        assert(result === expectedResult, "bad ${result} returned by testAsync")
        done()
    )
})
```

Comment: What if the `forEach` must use an async function because the test requires `await`? When there are errors, can I expect asynchronous functions to behave?

Comment: have made an edit - you can specify an `async` function and pass in a `done` callback to call when you're ready to

Comment: won't `done` get called multiple times in this case then?

Comment: ah yeah, sorry - good catch. I've adjusted the loop - untested but I'm pretty sure that will work.

Comment: Because there's an it `it` within the `forEach`, it looks like this might print multiple lines for the one test.

Comment: Yes, one line for every test

Comment: What I was asking in the original question was if there was a way to cleanly display it in one line, unless there was an error in which case the particular failed test data would be displayed

Comment: The `done()` will end the entire test suite as soon as the first test finishes. You need to put that `done()` outside the loop.

Comment: For your example, maybe you should run a `reduce` over your test data and then assert that the result should equal `[]`? That will show you any problem items.